# Grails GORM Criteria Query Eager Fetching

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have written a criteria query in a Grails service class where I expect an eager join to be performed, and to avoid lazy loading of child objects when displaying my results either as a JSON response or in my GSP.  The query executed as expected (setting my hibernate.show_sql=true in my DataSource.groovy I can see the query), but when I crawl the association in my GSP, I can see that Hibernate is executing subsequent queries as if it were lazily loading the associations.  I'm not convinced that the eager loading is actually working.  I do not want to set lazy:false within my domain class for these associations.

This is the criteria query:

```
def market = Market.withCriteria(uniqueResult:true){
    idEq(marketId)
    fetchMode 'resourceAssignments', FetchMode.JOIN
    fetchMode 'resourceAssignments.userRole', FetchMode.JOIN
    fetchMode 'resourceAssignments.userRole.role', FetchMode.JOIN
    fetchMode 'resourceAssignments.userRole.user', FetchMode.JOIN
    resourceAssignments{
        userRole{
            role{
                'in'('name', roleNames)
            }
        }
    }           
}
```

The above query returns without any issues.  When I attempt to run the following code, though, in my GSP, I can see that Hibernate is issuing a second query as if it were lazily fetching the resourceAssignments:

```
<g:each in="${market.resourceAssignments}" var="ra">
</g:each>
```

I even tried overriding the OpenSessionInViewInterceptor with a No-Op interceptor, by creating an empty WebRequestInterceptor and setting the openSessionInViewInterceptor in the resources.groovy to use it.  Once I did that, I get a org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException which seems to verify what I was thinking - that Hibernate or GORM is still trying to execute a second query even when I've specified that I want to eagerly fetch these associations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears to be a Grails bug with criteria queries. Here's an HQL query that works though:

```
def market = Market.executeQuery(
    'select m from Market m ' +
    'inner join fetch m.resourceAssignments as ra ' +
    'inner join fetch ra.userRole as ur ' +
    'inner join fetch ur.role as role ' +
    'inner join fetch ur.user as user ' +
    'where m.id=:marketId and role.name in (:roleNames)',
    [marketId: marketId, roleNames: roleNames], [max: 1])[0]
```

Comment: Thanks Burt.  We will use HQL until the bug is fixed.  Bobby Warner submitted a bug in Jira for this issue for those interested:  http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9829

Comment: The JIRA issue mentioned by @DavidMalone has been migrated to GitHub https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/2764