# Gorm criteria query to eager-fetch two one to many relationships, fetchMode doesn't work

Tags: join, grails-orm, criteria

I have a domain model - where Org has many sites, and has many domains (these are two 'bag' collection attributes).

I want to write a query that retrieves a single, and preferably the sites and domain collections in one hit.

I tried this first

```
org = Org.findById (id, [fetch:[sites:"eager", domains:"eager"]]
```

which fails with

> cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags: [com.softwood.domain.OrgRoleInstance.sites, com.softwood.domain.OrgRoleInstance.domains]

(It will work with only one of the two collections).

I tried a criteria query like this

```
    org = resource.withCriteria (uniqueResult: true) {
        fetchMode 'sites', FetchMode.SELECT
        fetchMode 'domains', FetchMode.SELECT
        idEq(id)
        sites {
            org {
                eq 'id', "$id"
            }
        }

    } // didn't work
```

which errors with this

> No signature of method: com.softwood.controller.OrgRoleInstanceController.fetchMode() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode) values: [sites, SELECT]

This indicates it doesn't like the fetchMode function, (using either SELECT or JOIN).

How do you write a criteria query to return a single matched object by id, but returns sites, and domains collections at the same time?

The domain class looks like this. I don't want to use the static mapping ={} closure - as i want to control the loading through writing explicit queries as required

```
class Org {

    enum OrgRoleType {
        Supplier,
        Customer,
        Service_Provider,
        Manufacturer,
        Maintainer,
        Indeterminate
    }

    String name
    OrgRoleType role
    Collection<NetworkDomain> domains = []
    Collection<Site> sites = []
    Collection<MaintenanceAgreement> mags       //optional only set if role is service provider
    //Collection<Device> ci

     static hasMany = [domains : NetworkDomain, sites: Site, mags:MaintenanceAgreement]

    static mappedBy  = [mags: "maintainer"]  //disambiguate column in mags


    static constraints = {
        name nullable:false
        role  nullable:true
        domains nullable:true
        sites nullable:true
        mags nullable:true  //optional
    }
}
```

I had seen this [[Grails GORM Criteria Query Eager Fetching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758499/grails-gorm-criteria-query-eager-fetching][1])

I'd tried to do similarly but the fetchMode (String, enum) just won't run.

### Update

I changed query to this

```
    org = resource.withCriteria (uniqueResult: true) {
        join 'sites' 
        join  'domains' 
        idEq(id)
        sites {
            org {
                eq 'id', "$id"
            }
        }
        domains {
            customer {
                eq 'id', "$id"
            }
        }

    }
```

This errors with

```
Cannot invoke method call() on null object
```

with the trace point to point where it access sites{org{ in the criteria.

Comment: i tried ( i think as sugested) and says cant invoke on null object when you access the sites{org{... selection).  see updated copy of query in above question added as extra

Answer (score 0):

First, testing has to be done as integration tests and not unit tests, however the result is you still can't do query finder with two eager loads.  if you want to load collections you have to use criteria or possibly a `where` clause to do so

Here are two integration tests - the first using finders fails with exception, the second achieves the goal using criteria query:

```
void "query by finderById with multiple eager fetch in map conditions " () {

    given :


    when: "we print value from a collection "

    def org = OrgRoleInstance.findById (7L, [fetch:[sites:"eager", domains:"eager"]])
    println org.domains[0].name

    then:
    org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException ex = thrown()


}

void "query withCriteria to do  multiple eager fetch in map conditions " () {

    given :


    def org = OrgRoleInstance.withCriteria (uniqueResult: true) {
        fetchMode 'sites', FetchMode.SELECT
        fetchMode 'domains', FetchMode.SELECT
        idEq (7L)
        sites {}
        domains {}

    }


    when: "we print value from a collection "

    println org.domains[0].name

    then:
    org.domains.size() == 1
    org.sites.size() == 2


}
```